# How to conditionally add CSS class to Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Can anyone help me how to add CSS class conditionally to Html.TextBoxFor in my razor view.

I am trying the following:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => model.DateTimeStamp, new { @readonly = "readonly"}, ViewBag.IsNew ? (object)new {@class="test" }:null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this..

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => model.DateTimeStamp, new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = ViewBag.IsNew ? "test" : "" })
```